# How to download respeller for resharper via NuGet?

Tags: c#, resharper, nuget

Note: I am a hobbyist C# programmer. I have no experience with NuGet (I'm not entirely sure what it's for).

I have Resharper (6 or 7, I think), and I want to install [Respeller Free](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSpeller/). However, there's no download link from that page, just a vague explanation about using NuGet...

...As always seems to be the case with these command-line things, there's no actual explanation anywhere on how to do this; just the standard blurb on why it's so much better...

Anyway, I've tried running this in the NuGet command line:

```
PM> Get-Package -filter spell -listavailable
```

But I can't see anything to do with respeller. So... What am I missing? Google turns up nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Resharper has it's own NuGet extension manager.

1: Go to the RESHARPER menu then select Extension Manager.

[image]

2: Respeller Free should be listed in the online section.

[image]

Comment: Hey... I don't seem to have that option: http://i.imgur.com/HqpE9fx.png ... I have Resharper 7.1.2 for what it's worth. (Also, please forgive my colour scheme... I got bored a few months ago, haha)

Comment: @Motig In that case try: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/plugins/list_plugins.jsp

Comment: Finally! I got an .msi. Thanks.

Comment: .msi no longer available, so you can't use respeller unless you're willing to pay for resharper